# IVI ocr Tesseract

Tags: c#, ocr, tesseract

Hi all I have a problem with the `OCR Tesseract` for C# (tessnet2) it find the caractère IVI and not "M" can you help me?

```
tessnet2.Tesseract ocr = new tessnet2.Tesseract();
         ocr.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"); // If digit only
         ocr.Init(@"C:\tresnet", "fra", false); // To use correct tessdata
         List<tessnet2.Word> result = ocr.DoOCR(imgSortie, Rectangle.Empty);
         String ListeLettres= "";
        
         foreach (tessnet2.Word word in result)
           ListeLettres= ListeLettres + word.Text;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@user2094482 Hi,

I was engaged with character recognition with Tesseract and c++. Once i faced the same problem. My system recognized |v| instead of M even the image was clear for my naked eye. I tried several image pre processing concepts such as image binarisation, image blur and etc to get accurate results. But none of those methods gave 100% accurate results for me. Therefore i  tried white listing and it  was a success.

```
text  = readLettersFromTesseractOCR(img_bw,&error,CharacterSequence);
```

CharacterSequence was initialized as below.

```
 CharacterSequence = ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789&lt
```

Hope this will work with your system as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would just using the Replace function for string and replace "IVI" with "M" since there are not many cases where "IVI" is actually written.